# SAS SQL or data step: How to select values that begin with different numbers

Tags: sas

Maybe the title is a bit blurry, I hope you will understand my question.

Background: I work with data about university students, and I have been given the task of calculating the grade point averages for all exams on a specific semester for some subset of predefined students. The time span of the data is 10 years and activity names for the exams varies across time.

My problem: Data has a hierarchy structure for the level of education, semester and activity names. How can I use a data step/SQL on the lowest level to select only those values beginning with value for the top hierarchy.

The hierarchy is the following (for a single student):

```
13109963 
1310996300001
131099630000100001
13109963000010000100001 (activities)
13109963000010000100002 (activities)
13109963000010000100003 (activities)
```

I have struggled with this for a few hours, and would appreciate suggestions how to proceed on this special problem. I have been using SAS for three years and have a background from the social sciences.

Thank you in advance
Henning

Comment: Which rows do you want to select in your example? Only the bottom three?

Comment: Please rephrase or elaborate on "How can I use a data step/SQL on the lowest level to select only those values beginning with value for the top hierarchy." ... it's confusing. What is "lowest level", what is "top hierarchy"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options in SAS that will let you accomplish this task.

Here is a quick example.

```
 data sample;
length  level $60.;
input  level $1-60;
/*Option 1
 Subset obs based on top hierarchy and select bottom hierarchy
 based on the length of the string
*/
opt1 = substr(level,1,8)='13109963' and length(level)>23 ;
/*Option 2
 Subset obs based on the length of the string to pick all lowest level regardless
 of the top hierarchy (in this case will return the same result)
*/
opt2 = length(level)>23 ;
/* Option 3:
 if all lowest level  hierarchies have a '(' you can then use the index function
*/
opt3 = index(level,'(')>1;
/* Option 4: Is using regex but I think any of the above will suffice*/
cards;
13109963 
1310996300001
131099630000100001
13109963000010000100001 (activities)
13109963000010000100002 (activities)
13109963000010000100003 (activities) 
;
run;
```

You can also mix&match any of the options above to select only those observations required.
For example: `if substr(level,1,8)='13109963'and index(level,'(')>1;` will return the same result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems to work just for this single student. Maybe I'm mistaken. My problem is more general for thousands of students with the same data structure as the one indicated above. I've found a way to muddle throught iteratively down the hierarchy of the data using many DATA STEPS and SQL'S. Maybe there's a smarter way to do things :-)

Comment: I think you need to better explain your problem then cos is not clear

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me. I've found a way through my problem.